# How to read an excel file that contains array of json

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am trying to read an excel file , which contains only one column , and its an array of json , I am not able to read it by apache-poi in the form of string .

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); 
XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
int index = 0;

for (index = 0; index < worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); index++) {
    if (index > 0) {
        XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(index);
        String b = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

This code is not returning the value of the columns in string form.
Please tell me - how can I read the col values in string as it is?

[Sample of Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Vi1.png)

Comment: What output does it give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem once try this

```
HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        for(Row row: sheet)
        {
            for(Cell cell: row)
            {
                switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType())
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+ "\t\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t\t");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

I took the input in .xls file like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QH9d.png)

and this is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwJZ1.png)